# How to set static field on Display Suite

Tags: 7, display-suite

i would like to set a static field using [Display Suite](https://www.drupal.org/project/ds) in Drupal 7 but don´t know how.
It´s a text snippet that won´t change so i want to place it using a field.

Can somebody help me how to do it?

Thank you very much.

Kind Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create custom fields at admin/structure/ds/fields. You can maybe add a code field for entity Nodes with your text snippet and then place it in your custom DS layout for a content type.

Answer (score 1):

Add a code field to Display Suite. In that code field you add your html (with token support if token is installed). Then just place the code field in the display tab for the content type.

Tutorial [here](https://drupalize.me/videos/display-suite-fields?p=1141).